# Using MediaCodec to stream high quality video with less data consumed

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

We're using MediaCodec to consume videos from network to our android app.
In some cases although there is high resolution video available (720p or higher) we would like to consume it in lower resolution in the Android app in order to save data consumption.

Is there an option to consume high resolution video in lower resolution portion, even if there is no available video with lower resolution?
Maybe consume it with lower frame rate? Other alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: _"In some cases"_ are you not in charge of the videos that you play? If not, then no you can only download whatever the other server offers. If in charge, then save multiple resolution copies of the same video.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One, so basically no option for this as I'm not the owner of the video in all cases